# InDesign document printing in wrong font

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, print-design, page-layout, cs5

I have an Adobe InDesign CS5 document that I'm trying to print.  It is set in Gill Sans Light.  Here is a snippet of the document:

[image: InDesign image in Gill Sans]

However, when I print the document it comes out like this:

[image: Prints in weird font]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

EDIT - I think that this might be a printer driver issue, but I'm not sure.  The printers that I'm using are a HP LaserJet P3005n and a HP LaserJet P3015.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to give us another url for the image or import it somewhere else than where is it right now? It seems like we don't have the permission to access the content and we (at least, I) can't see it!

Comment: There's some issue with the images, can you edit your question and re-add your images using the editor's button?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to deal with that.

Comment: ostrich, you need to save your images locally and then use the image button in the editor to upload them. Stack Exchange will save them with Imgur to make them available.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I tried but there was no button to press after uploading the photo.

Comment: If you can't add it to the question (there may be a limit on the number of images based on your reputation), then upload it somewhere public and put the URL in a comment. Once someone else can access it, they can edit the question and add the image for you. It's actually the "wrong" image which is more important than the "right" one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure a specific answer but - somethings to try.

Is the font legit?  If not, uninstall it and find a better version.

Was the font installed while In-Design was open?  If so, restart.

Try exporting PDF. If that looks good, print from the PDF

Comment: I actually suggested exporting it to my teacher.  (This is for a school newspaper.)  It's an acceptable workaround, but it would take longer than otherwise.  The font, Gill Sans, actually comes installed with Mac OS, and has always worked for me in the past; this problem just started popping up.